# cannot resolve own defined golang package with vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have no clue but suddenly my vscode became unable to resolve to own package.

[image]

building main.go succeeds so I think the code itself does not have a problem.

I'm sorry for lucking information but if anyone encountered the same problem and solved it, please tell me how. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

this was due to I updated to experimental version for golang language server

I completely reinstalled vscode and it worked again

Answer (score 0):

Same situation Happend for me long time main reasons vscode crash/old versions compatibility or may be other issue.
go side pkg section not able 'get' the proper info